# algebraic structure consisting of two fields with common multiplication operation

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am looking for properties of an algebraic structure on a set defined as follows:
- two fields with distinct operations of addition (thus two distinct additive zeros) and a common operation of multiplication.

An example would be the set  $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers and two operations of addition defined on it.  For $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$:

- one is the usual addition $a+b$;
- the other is $a\dot{+}b=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}}$.

The inverse of $a\in \mathbb{R}$ under both operations is $-a$.  The additive zero of  $+$ operation is the $0$, the additive zero of $\dot{+}$ is $\infty$ if we allow $\infty=\frac{1}{0}$.

Any mention, examples, thoughts would be very welcome.

Comment: This is not clear.  Can you give a detailed example of the structure you have in mind?

Comment: underlying set is a set of complex numbers.  I define two operations of addition, so that both yield commutative groups with distinct zero elements.  the operation of multiplication is the usual multiplication of complex numbers.

Comment: In particular, how could there be two different additive zeroes?  Since $0_i\times x=0_i$ for all $x$ in the field we see that $0_1\times 0_2=0_2\times 0_1$ is both $0_1$ and $0_2$.

Comment: that is the question I don't like :).  0 and infinity are the two zeros and yes, their product messes up everything.  Separately, two additions define two different fields.  But since the multiplication is common I am looking for possible similarities in other areas.

Comment: Right now I consider two fields that are unrelated; that eliminates the concern you mentioned.  But may be there are examples out there...

Comment: Not following.  As a general rule, it's a bad idea to talk about algebraic structures with no examples in mind. The formalism is meant to generalize the properties you observe in particular examples. Here, I don't think you have any actual examples in mind.  If you do, please edit your post to describe one or two examples in detail.

Comment: The example is a set of all solutions of an ordinary differential equation.  It has been shown that there are two operations of addition that define two commutative groups on this set.

Comment: Again, not following.  If you have a precise example, please edit your post to include a detailed discussion of it.

Comment: I see, I do have a precise example, but writing it up would take a bit longer.  May I take time out.  Thank you so much for your comments.

Comment: An example is as follows.  If $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$ are solutions to one-dimensional homogeneous linear ordinary differential equation $u'(t)=u$, then $u_{1} + u_{2}$ is a solution as well, where '+' is the usual addition.
We can define an operation of addition of ${u_{1}}$ and ${u_{2}}$ differently: $u_{1}\dot{+}u_{2} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}u_{1}+\frac{1}{u_{2}}}$.  The $\dot{+}$ sum is a solution to the equation above (checked by substitution). Operation $\dot{+}$ defines a commutative group on the set of solutions:  the additive zero in this case is ${\infty}$ if we allow $0=\frac{1}{\infty}$.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the example.    But...I'm not clear on the example.  for the equation $y'=y$ the solutions are $ae^x$ for $a\in \mathbb R$.  The usual addition is just the usual addition of reals.  The other operation appears to take $a,b$ to $\frac {ab}{a+b}$, yes?  You want the inverse of $a$ to just be $-a$ as before, yes?

Comment: When you edit your post, I'd drop the bit about the ODE.  you have two "additions" on $\mathbb R$, the usual one and $a\dot + b =\frac {ab}{a+b}$  There really isn;t an additive identity for the second, but you can squint and pretend there is.  Both distribute over the usual multiplication.

Comment: You are right about the other operation and about the (other) inverse of $a$.

Comment: In the example you don't have two field structures *on the same set*. The joint set is $S=\Bbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$. You have one field structure on the set $S\setminus\{\infty\}$ and another on $S\setminus\{0\}$. They happen to share the multiplicative group, but the zero of one is outside the other field altogether.

Comment: It is important that you remove $0$ from the second set, else you wind up with $0\,\dot +\, b=0\,\,\forall \,b\in \mathbb R$ which is hard to reconcile.

Comment: The argument against removing ${0}$ is that it is a solution of the differential equation to start with.

Comment: and both these operations of addition do come as defined on the solution set of the differential equation in the first place, not just on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Well, but $\infty$ isn't a solution to that ODE.  And if you include $0$, the second binary operation isn't very like an addition.

Comment: It may sound stupid, but may I come up with a structure that allows for both $0$ and $\infty$ and takes care of inconveniences that you pointed out? I surely cannot remove $0$ solution but I can "extend" my solution set to include $\infty$, the way $\mathbb{R}$ is extended sometimes.

Comment: I don't see a sensible way to extend the definitions that doesn't lead to one or another of the problems we have already mentioned.

Comment: Thank you so much for explanatory comments and gained clarity.